# Postgresql: Which is faster: query with OR clause, or two separate queries?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Between these two queries, which one is faster for the database to execute?

```
select a, b, c from t where x = y or x = z;
```

vs.

```
select a, b, c from t where x = y;
select a, b, c from t where x = z;
```

Either one is fine for my application because the results will be put into a map that will automatically remove duplicates. So then I wonder if there is a technical reason one is more preferable than the other.

Comment: [Just Race Your Horse](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Answer (score 2):

They should be pretty much the same if you have an index on `x` and `y` and `z` are constants.

If `y` and `z` are columns, then indexes will not help.  If no indexes can be used, then the version with `or` should be about twice as fast, because it scans the table only once rather than twice.

Answer (score 1):

As you are selecting same cols from one single table with Two different conditions you can try union operator

```
Select a,b,c from tab1 where d=cond1 union select a,b,c from tab1 where d=cond2
```